# Experiment on Parallel class

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm working an experiment which involves threading and currently, I'm using Parallel class. I made a program that fetches data and I assume that we're retrieving them in different intervals. If we're going to call them one by one or synchronous, the elapse time will be 9 seconds. But if I use the Parallel.Invoke, It saves time (5 seconds) and I think more productive because we're maximizing the server threads. My question is, is this good approach? or there's any drawbacks?  Let's assume I use this approach to a web application which it  has 20 - 30 users (or more). (Server would be an average specs or below)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    bool output1 = false;
    bool output2 = false;
    bool output3 = false;

    //9 seconds
    //output1 = FetchData1();
    //output2 = FetchData2();
    //output3 = FetchData3();

    Parallel.Invoke(() => output1 = FetchData1(), () => output2 = FetchData2(), () => output3 = FetchData3());

    //Process(output1, output2, output3);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static bool FetchData1()
{
    //db call 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("FetchData1");
    return true;
}

static bool FetchData2()
{
    //db call 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("FetchData2");
    return true;
}

static bool FetchData3()
{
    //db call 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("FetchData3");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, threading is a popular technique when executing multiple operations which are not IO bound (such as fetching data from another source).

Comment: Thanks Rob. So it is safe to use the Parallel.Invoke, in more than 30 users simultaneously calling the method.